# Autocompletion in Pydev- Eclipse for wxpython

Tags: java, c++, python, eclipse, wxpython

How can I activate autocompletion feature for wx classes in pyDev? I cannot find anything to prompt me to change that will activate this feature from PyDev>Preference>Autocompletion. How can I get autocompletion from packages like wx and other third-party packages?

Update:

I added wx path in configuration to pyDev and it now shows autocompletion for wx. However, I cannot see the method arguments and properties. For example if I seek for wx.Button, I just get autocompletion to complete writing Button but I want to know the required arguments for wx.Button as wx.Button(,....,size,pos...) etc. This works for the other methods of built-in methods when I press Ctrl+Space but I don't know how should I configure to get that from wx and other third party packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding missing parameters on the constructor for wx.Button, unfortunately that's currently expected. Please create a bug report for PyDev specifying that.